# DS3231 doesn't update its internal time?

Tags: i2c, rtc, ds1307

**UPD**: with another chip of the same model RTC works just fine, presumably that the chip was broken/damaged.

I installed [DS3231 RTC clock](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1pc-DS3231-Precision-RTC-Module-Memory-Module-for-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi/251544821678) ( which is detected as DS1307 for some reason). My config.txt looks like

```
gpu_mem=64
dtoverlay=dwc2
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c_arm_baudrate=1000000
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
```

The clock is detected by `i2cdetect` and I can see that `/dev/rtc0` exists.

`dmesg | grep rtc` shows

```
dmesg | grep rtc
[    4.021947] rtc-ds1307 1-0068: registered as rtc0
```

The problem is - `hwclock -r` always returns the **same** time. I can set it with `hwclock -w` and it will keep **that very time** for weeks.

Am I missing something there? Isn't it supposed to *tick*?

Comment: it is probably a DS1307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **ONLY** thing you have to do is include in /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
```

All the RTC supported by the Pi kernel use the same rtc-ds1307 driver, but you NEED to tell the driver which chip you actually have. (The different chips have similar instruction sets and registers.)

NOTE you NEED to use a separate dtoverlay line for each overlay. Putting dwc2,i2c-rtc will not work.

There is no need to set time - it all happens AUTOMATICALLY, although you can set the RTC initially (if NTP not available) using hwclock --set see man hwclock for details.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51782/8697

Comment: okay, easy - looks like the chip is buggy itself, tried with another one - worked just fine.